# How to disable the visual bell in Xterm

Tags: linux, defaults

I am getting really nervous when I press 'Tab' twice and screen is blinking (goes to opposite color and returns back).

I tried to change the setting in `.Xdefaults` file with:

```
XTerm*visualBell:  False
```

but could not get rid of this.

I also tried to kill the VNC process and re-created but it still doesn't work!

Does anybody have a solution for removing this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem: in my home directory there wan another .Xresources file in which it was written

```
XTerm*visualBell: True
```

So Xterm was initializing from not .Xdefaults but from .Xresources! Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To disable it on a single xterm: Control middle-click on the xterm, and unselect 'Enable Visual Bell'

The default (according to the manpage) setting for the visual bell is off, so it must be getting turned on somewhere.

Run:

```
xrdb -query |grep -i ^xterm
```

And see if the visualBell resource is set.

To disable it for your current session, run:

```
echo 'xterm*visualBell: false' | xrdb -merge
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xterm or gnome-terminal?

If the latter, the instructions [here](http://evanjones.ca/ubuntu-tips.html) show how to turn on the visual bell. I've copied and reversed the instructions so you can turn it off:

- Be sure gnome-terminal has the bell enabled: In the Gnome Terminal menu: Edit > Profile Preferences > Terminal Bell must be checked. Pressing backspace at a prompt should cause an annoying audible beep.
- Turn on window flashing: In the Gnome menu: System > Preferences > Sound, click on the Sounds tab, Change the "Visual alert" setting to "Disabled."
- Enable the audible bell. In the same panel, check the "Play alert sound" check box.

Or you could edit the file `~/.gconf/apps/metacity/general/%gconf.xml` and change this line so that it has "true" in it (yes, "true" for "off") as shown:

```
<entry name="visual_bell" mtime="1253605354" type="bool" value="true"/>
```

Also, as a workaround, in `csh` you can:

```
set nobeep
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
xset b off
```

greetz

Comment: That’s the audible bell, AFAIK.

Comment: I'd nerver saw it works! In OPENBSD, in Debian...

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way I do it:

```
rmmod pcspkr
```

Comment: That does a lot more (potentially unwanted) things than just turn off the `BEL`.

Answer (score -1):

~/.inputrc:

```
set bell-style none
```

Comment: doesn't work! BTW I am using csh via VNC.